# Cancel auto row selection after refresh xceed datagrid

Tags: select, datagrid, refresh, xceed

It seems that xceed data grid selects a cell/row from the datagrid after every refresh. I don't want to have this behavior in my datagrid. Is there a way to remove this behavior?